# Decode Oracle in Linq to EF

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I need to convert the code bellow to Linq to EF.

How can I do it?

```
  FROM
       ACECPGER_OEE.META_OEE M
      ,ACECPGER_OEE.PR_EQUIPAMENTO P
 WHERE 
       DECODE(M.COD_EQPMT_PRODC, 'FP1', 'FPA', M.COD_EQPMT_PRODC) = P.COD_EQPMT_PRODC
```